# Observed LiveData doesn't really update after first fetch

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm building an offline-first app with the database setup as the single source of truth. I am using Room to simplify the database handling, and LiveData to simplify observable data patterns.

I am also using Retrofit to make any network calls required to populate the database with new data.

I have set up an observer in my Fragment as follows:

```
private void setUpObserver() {
        tfViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(TFViewModel.class);
        tfViewModel.getAllPosts().observe(getActivity(),
                newPosts -> {
                    if (newPosts != null && newPosts.size() > 0) {
                        lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mPostsAdapter.updateItems(newPosts);
                    }
                });
        tfViewModel.fetchNextData(currentPage);
}
```

When my app first starts, I'm deleberately truncating each table in my database using Room callbacks so that new data is fetched every time. (For testing. This beats the offline-first experience and must not be done in production.)

Anyway, so when it first starts, it calls the `fetchNextData` method of the viewmodel which in turn asks the Repository to fetch the data.

Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class TFViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private TFRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Post>> mPostList;

    public TFViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new TFRepository(application);
        mPostList = mRepository.getAllPosts();
    }


    public LiveData<List<Post>> getAllPosts() {
        return mPostList;
    }

    public void fetchNextData(int page) {
        mRepository.fetchNextPosts(page);
    }

}
```

In the repository, I use my DAOs to insert posts into the database. To fetch new data, I use a Service Class to fetch new data for me. When the fetch call returns, I use an AsyncTask to insert the new posts to my database. (Details omitted for brevity):

```
public class TFRepository {

    private PostDao postDao;

    private LiveData<List<Post>> postList;

    private RetrofitSingleton retrofitSingleton;

    public TFRepository(Application application) {
        TFRoomDatabase db = TFRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);

        postDao = db.postDao();
        retrofitSingleton = RetrofitSingleton.getInstance(application.getApplicationContext());
        postList = postDao.getAllPosts();

    }

    public LiveData<List<Post>> getAllPosts() {
        return postList;
    }

    public void fetchNextPosts(int page) {
        getPostList(page);
    }

    private void getPostList(int page) {

        APICaller.getInstance(retrofitSingleton).getFeed(page,
                new NetworkResponseListener<BaseResponse<FeedResponse>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponseReceived(BaseResponse<FeedResponse> feedResponseBaseResponse) {

                        if (feedResponseBaseResponse == null) return;

                        List<Post> posts = feedResponseBaseResponse.getData().getPosts();
                        new insertAllPostsAsyncTask(postDao).execute(posts);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(String errorMessage) {
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

The OBSERVER I had setup in my fragment **gets an empty list the first time** around. The API call returns with the first page of posts and **it receives 10 posts the second time.** The view is popualted. Everything is good.

**Problem:** As the user scrolls down, the Fragment asks the ViewModel to fetch more data. The ViewModel asks the Repository to fetch new data. The **Retrofit** **call goes and comes back with the new data**. It is inserted in the database. **BUT THE OBSERVER IS NOT NOTIFIED.** What am I missing?

NOTE: I do not want to use a **`MutableLiveData`** as I want to maintain the DB as the single source of truth. Also, as the docs state that **LiveData is notified whenever the underlying DB changes**, my implementation should work with LiveData.

Comment: In your AsyncTask, do you just call dao.insert?

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I do.

Comment: Your livedata is not registering a change in the list, even though there is one. When fetching your second page, does the list size change?

Comment: The list size remains the same (10) but the objects that are returned do change.

Comment: This might be your problem. Try either appending the list (and then in your fragment just getting the second 10 items) or overwrite the isEqual method for your list (I think this is what's being used but need to check..)

Comment: Also, can you post your select query (from the dao).

Comment: I guess you have DB query with limit 10, as per your comment. Try after removing that.

Comment: The question was: "When fetching your second page, does the list size change?" and that's what I answered. (The items returned by the fetch query have a limit, not the local Room query.)